# Sqlserver - three tables and ban list

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables: *users*, *items* and *lockeditems*

I want to show everything from **items**, but if an user want to hide an item then i add his userid and itemid to locked list

```
[users]
userid
username

[items]
itemid
itemname

[lockeditems]
itemid
userid
```

sqlserver,
how to select all [items] but dont show items from itemlocked list by [itemid] and [userid]?

thanks, sorry for not formatting

Comment: How do you know who the user is?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74189/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    ([userid] int, [username] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO users
    ([userid], [username])
VALUES
    (1, 'John'),
    (2, 'Mary')
;

CREATE TABLE items
    ([itemid] int, [itemname] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO items
    ([itemid], [itemname])
VALUES
    (1, 'saw'),
    (2, 'hammer')
;

CREATE TABLE lockeditems
    ([itemid] int, [userid] int)
;

INSERT INTO lockeditems
    ([itemid], [userid])
VALUES
    (1, 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select u.userid, i.*
from users u
cross join items i 
left outer join lockeditems l on u.userid = l.userid and i.itemid = l.itemid
where l.userid is null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74189/1/0)**:

```
| USERID | ITEMID | ITEMNAME |
|--------|--------|----------|
|      1 |      2 |   hammer |
|      2 |      1 |      saw |
|      2 |      2 |   hammer |
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the user in a variable, say `@TheUserId`, then this is a good use of the `not exists` clause:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from lockeditems li
                  where li.userid = @TheUserId and
                        li.itemid = i.itemid
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Users u 
    CROSS JOIN Items i
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * 
     FROM lockeditems li
     WHERE li.userID = u.userid AND i.itemid = li.itemid);
```

[Except](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) will also work

```
SELECT  u.UserId, i.ItemId 
    FROM Users u 
    CROSS JOIN Items i
EXCEPT
    SELECT li.UserId, li.ItemID
     FROM lockeditems li;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fccb5/3)

Comment: first option worked but swapped users to items, just had to group by to show items only, will post how i did it later, thanks!

Comment: OK, as per Gordon's comment, it wasn't clear who the subject 'user' was. I assumed you want all users.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE users (  
userid int,
username varchar(20))

CREATE TABLE  items (
itemid int,
itemname varchar(20))

CREATE TABLE lockeditems (
itemid int,
userid int)

INSERT INTO users VALUES  (1,'Adam'),(2,'Johan'),(3,'Jennifer'),(4,'Rajanand'),(5,'Jason')
INSERT INTO items VALUES  (10,'Keyboard'),(20,'Mouse'),(30,'CPU'),(40,'Hard drive'),(50,'RAM')
INSERT INTO lockeditems VALUES (30,3),(50,5)

SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid FROM lockeditems)
SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemid NOT IN (SELECT itemid FROM lockeditems)
```

Comment: thats exactly! how my tables look like, but select methods dont get me item results